# Put string on byte-like object in python

Tags: python

I have a problem with concatenating two encoded strings in python.
Below string is which I want to have after concatenating :

```
a = b"\x50\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x97\x15\x0d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8d\x0a"
```

But i want to dynamicly append `\x97\x15` part of string to it, my solution is like below:

```
def convert(deviceId):
        return r"\x{}\x{}".format(str(hex(int(deviceId))).replace("0x", "")[2:].strip(), str(hex(int(deviceId))).replace("0x", "")[:2].strip())

b = "\x50\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00{}\x0d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8d\x0a".format(convert(5527))
```

but this `a` and `b` variables are not the same, i calculate the hash of `a` and `b` and they are not the same.
How can I fix this?
The `convert()` function is used to convert a number to hex and reverse each piece of the hex, for example, the hex of `5527` is `0x1597` and I should receive `\x97\x15` in this function and put it in the middle of the string `a`. is there another way to convert `5527` to `\x97\x15` and put it in the middle of the string `a`?

Answer (score 0):

Your *convert* function is incorrect, and this is because a general confusion about ***\x97\x15***:

1. What it actually is: the *hex* representation of *5527* - 2 bytes in ***big endian*** order (*0x97*, *0x15*), or characters with the *ASCII* codes: 151, 21
2. What you think it is: the "stringized" form of the above (what *repr* would return) - an 8 byte string with the following *char*s: '*\*', '*x*', '*9*', '*7*', '*\*', '*x*', '*1*', '*5*'

> ```py
> >>> def convert_orig(deviceId):
> ...     return r"\x{}\x{}".format(str(hex(int(deviceId))).replace("0x", "")[2:].strip(), str(hex(int(deviceId))).replace("0x", "")[:2].strip())
> ...
> >>>
> >>> co = convert_orig(5527)
> >>> co, len(co)
> ('\\x97\\x15', 8)
> >>>
> >>> def convert_new(device_id):  # Does NOT work for numbers wider than 2 bytes (greater than 65536)
> ...     return "".join(chr(i) for i in reversed(divmod(device_id, 256)))
> ...
> >>> cn = convert_new(5527)
> >>> cn, len(cn)
> ('\x97\x15', 2)
> ```